# Why is my CSS not remove left and right margins?

Tags: html, css, mobile, margin

I'm trying to remove all white space on the left and right side of my [blog](http://jeffreydowellphotography.com/blog/) in mobile view, and only have white space between posts.

I'm trying to remove it with this code, but somehow I'm not selecting the right thing.

```
#collection-51ca14b1e4b014f2c6e0c3e7 #pageWrapper #canvasWrapper #canvas {
    margin-left: 0px!important;
    margin-right: 0px!important;
    padding-left: 0px!important;
    padding-right: 0px!important;
}
```

An image demonstrating this can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9E1OP.png).

Comment: umm.. body { margin:0px; padding: 0px;}

Comment: it didn't seem to change anything

Comment: !important is a blunt too and usually a sign of bad code.

Comment: its a template base site from squarespace, so i cant edit the original code, i can only add stuff to over-write it.

Comment: You can't overwrite !important, that's why it's dangerous.

Comment: its all coz of the padding to pagewrapper ! wait i find some workaround, if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space is from the `left`/`right` padding on `#pageWrapper`.

You would therefore change

```
#pageWrapper {
    padding: 0px 20px;
}
```

to

```
#pageWrapper {
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how often you are declaring padding within `#pageWrapper`. You need to go through it and remove it.

```
#pageWrapper {
padding: 0px 20px;
}

// you only need to remove the padding from this for mobile to be effected only
site.css:8889@media only screen and (max-width: 640px)
#header, #pageWrapper, #footer {
padding: 30px 20px;
margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}
// you only need to remove the padding from this for mobile to be effected only


site.css:8277@media only screen and (max-width: 800px)
#header, #pageWrapper, #footer {
padding: 30px 20px;
}
#pageWrapper {
border: 0px solid #ffffff;
border-width: 0px 0;
padding: 0 10px;
clear: both;
}
```